# How to fix the ValidationException with AWS amplify mock api

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I get the exception ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value
when I click on the Play button as instructed in an [AWS workshop page](https://amplify-sns.workshop.aws/en/30_mock/20_post_back_end.html). Any advice would be really helpful!

```
AppSync Mock endpoint is running at http://192.168.20.3:20002
Error while executing Local DynamoDB
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "PutItem",
    "attributeValues": {
        "type": {
            "S": "post"
        },
        "content": {
            "S": "test"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "N": "1668425585"
        },
        "owner": {
            "S": "7d8ca528-4931-4254-9273-ea5ee853f271::user1"
        },
        "__typename": {
            "S": "Post"
        }
    },
    "condition": {
        "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
        "expressionNames": {
            "#id": "id"
        }
    },
    "key": {}
}
ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value
```

Schema file

```
input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public }
} # FOR TESTING ONLY!
type Post
  @model(
    mutations: { create: "createPost", delete: "deletePost", update: null }
    timestamps: null
    subscriptions: { level: public }
  )
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "owner"
        provider: userPools
        operations: [read, create, delete]
      }
      { allow: private, provider: userPools, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  type: String! # always set to 'post'. used in the SortByTimestamp GSI
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  owner: String
  timestamp: Int!
}
```

(I tried adding and removing the exclamation to the **ID** here)

Screenshot
[image]